# What system function and cp command return in C/Linux

Tags: c, linux

Here i used below in code on linux.
using cp command in system function.

I know about system function it will return the 0 if command successfully executed.otherwise it will return error code.

If here i use proper source and destination path than i got output like this

```
Number == 0
```

If i give wrong source and destination path than i got

```
cp: cannot create regular file `/home/sam/test/test': No such file or directory
Number == 256

cp: cannot stat `/home/sam/main/test2/test': Not a directory
Number == 256
```

Here i want to know the error code of `cp` command what cp command return here.

My questions are here

```
1 System function return error code of cp command?
2 Can i get error code of cp command from source code of cp command?
3 i want to handle all types of error in this cp command.
```

code :

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void main()
{
    int a;
    a = system("cp /home/sam/main/test /home/sam");
    printf("Number == %d\n",a);
}
```

So any body please Explain me about this all

Comment: Please stop using void main(). The main() function should return int. (what would happen if the creators of cp or sh would have used `void main()`? )

Comment: Why don't use mmap() or open()/read()/write() to copy files instead of using system() to execute the cp command?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The correct way to user the return value of system is with the [wait-specific macros](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/waitpid.html).

```
if (WIFEXITED(a)) {
    int rc;
    rc = WEXITSTATUS(a);
    printf("Exit with status: %d\n", rc);
} else {
    /* Killed by a signal. */
}
```

Comment: What about my output when cp command fails and its gives 256? its status of cp command or error code of system funtcion?

Comment: @user1089679 It's nothing. It's a small integer that's meaningless without the macros I showed you.

Answer (score 1):

The man page of `system` states:

> RETURN VALUE
>          The value returned is -1 on error (e.g.  fork(2) failed), and the return status of the command otherwise.  This latter return
>          status  is  in  the  format  specified  in wait(2).  Thus, the exit code of the command will be WEXITSTATUS(status).  In case
>          /bin/sh could not be executed, the exit status will be that of a command that does exit(127).
>
> If the value of command is NULL, system() returns nonzero if the shell is available, and zero if not.
>   system() does not affect the wait status of any other children.

So, you can get the exit status with `WEXITSTATUS(a)` whene `WIFEXITED(a)` is true.

In general, the possible exit codes of a command are specified in the manpage. For `cp`, there is no documentation, so you can't rely on anything. You might think of going with lower-level system commands (such as `open` or `link`).

Comment: What about in my output 256 ?

Answer (score 1):

256 typically means there was a permission issue

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/privileges/comment).